# Centered Fixed Marker on Xamarin.Forms.Maps

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, google-maps-markers, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to integrate a map on Xamarin.Forms that when opened, a fixed marker is placed on the center of the map. By fixed, I mean it does not move when the map is dragged and the marker itself is also not draggable. Can somebody guide me through this or do you have any reference that I can read on? I already have the map displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add a marker to the map, but instead overlay the map with a view on top of it.

Comment: Forgot to update this question and yes, that's what I did yesterday and I got it working. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and after searching for very long, I finally combined some parchments and logic to arrive at a solution that FINALLY WORKED. I posted a COMPLETE SOLUTION to the Centred Marker problem on Github, here is the link.

[https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/issues/486](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhlMO.jpg)

but for the purpose of redundancy (in case you can't find the post for one reason or the other), here is the solution

```
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout x:Name="PanelMain"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical"  VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="10,0,10,0">
                    <Label x:Name="lblTotal" FontSize="14" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="[Address Show Here]" />
                    <Label x:Name="lblCoordinates" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="[GPS Coordinates]" />

                    <SearchBar x:Name="SearchTextBox" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" CancelButtonColor="Red" SearchButtonPressed="SearchTextBox_SearchButtonPressed" Placeholder="Search for Destination"></SearchBar>

                    <ActivityIndicator  IsVisible="False" x:Name="MyActivityIndicator" Color="#039763" IsRunning="False"></ActivityIndicator>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout x:Name="mystacklayout" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
             
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">
                    <synbtn:SfButton x:Name="cmdGetCoordinateDestination" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#E66C2C" BorderColor="#039763" HasShadow="False"  TextColor="White" FontSize="14" HeightRequest="42" Text="Get GPS Coordinates" Clicked="cmdGetCoordinateDestination_Clicked"></synbtn:SfButton>
                    <synbtn:SfButton x:Name="cmdSUBMIT" CornerRadius="7" IsVisible="False" IsEnabled="True" BorderColor="LightGray" HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="#039763" TextColor="White" FontSize="16" HeightRequest="45" Text="SUBMIT REPORT" Clicked="CreateAccountClicked"></synbtn:SfButton>

                    <!--<Label x:Name="lbldistance" Text="Within 50 Kilometers (KM)" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="11" />
                <syncslider:SfRangeSlider x:Name="theSlider" HeightRequest="60" ShowRange="False" SnapsTo="StepValues" StepFrequency="20" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TickPlacement="Inline" ValueChangeMode="Default" Minimum="0" Maximum="300" Value="50" ValueChanging="theSlider_ValueChanging"></syncslider:SfRangeSlider>-->
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout x:Name="mycentremarker_layout" IsVisible="True" Padding="12"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1">

        </StackLayout>             
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Now, combine this with some C# code for adding and initializing the Xamarin.Forms.Map and the Centre Marker Icon to the page

```
private async void PrepareMap()
    {
        try
        { 
            var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium);
            var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(true);

            if (location != null)
            {
                App.lastlatitude = location.Latitude; //double.Parse("8.13463");
                App.lastlongitude = location.Longitude; //double.Parse("-13.30254");
            }
        
            if (App.lastlatitude != 0)
            {
                var position = new Position(App.lastlatitude, App.lastlongitude);

                customMap = new CustomMap
                {
                    MapType = MapType.Street,
                    IsShowingUser = true,
                    WidthRequest = 100,
                    HeightRequest = 100,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                };

                customMap.MapType = MapType.Street;
                customMap.TrafficEnabled = true;

                if (mystacklayout.Children.Any())
                {
                    mystacklayout.Children.Clear();
                }

                mystacklayout.Children.Add(customMap);

                    customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(App.lastlatitude, App.lastlongitude), Distance.FromMiles(5)));
            
                customMap.IsShowingUser = true;

                TheCoordinates = App.lastlatitude + ", " + App.lastlongitude;

                var thelatdecimal = App.lastlatitude.ToString().Split('.')[1];
                var thelongdecimal = App.lastlongitude.ToString().Split('.')[1];

                if (thelatdecimal.Length > 5)
                {
                    thelatdecimal = thelatdecimal.Substring(0, 5);
                }

                if (thelongdecimal.Length > 5)
                {
                    thelongdecimal = thelongdecimal.Substring(0, 5);
                }

                var thelat = App.lastlatitude.ToString().Split('.')[0] + "." + thelatdecimal;
                var thelong = App.lastlongitude.ToString().Split('.')[0] + "." + thelongdecimal;

                lblCoordinates.Text = thelat + ", " + thelong;

                AddTheCentreMarker();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK").ConfigureAwait(true);
        }
    }

    private async void AddTheCentreMarker()
    {
        try
        {

            Image _imgMarker = new Image();  //marker holder declaration
            int int_markerSize; //marker sizer 
            _imgMarker.Source = Device.OnPlatform(
                iOS: ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("http://www.launchappy.com/images/Marker.png")),
                Android: ImageSource.FromFile("Marker.png"),
                WinPhone: ImageSource.FromFile("Marker.png"));
            _imgMarker.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            int_markerSize = 20;
            _imgMarker.WidthRequest = int_markerSize;
            _imgMarker.HeightRequest = int_markerSize;

            mycentremarker_layout.Children.Add(_imgMarker);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps to solve the problem

[image]
[image]